# Highchart legend

Tags: highcharts, pagination, legend

I added a button to my chart to toggle (show/hide) the chart legend.
To hide my legend, I'm using in the callback function:
`legend.group.hide()

 Legend.box.hide()`

This is working great, but when the legend is hidden, the legend pagination (legend paging navigation) remain visible on the chart.
How can I also hide the legend navigation?

Comment: I checked both solution suggested by yuk and by Sebastian Bochan and they both working great, thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refer to down/up/pager objects and hide them too.

```
$('#updateLegend').click(function (e) {
        var legend = chart.legend;
        if(legend.display) {
            legend.group.hide();
            legend.down.hide();
            legend.up.hide();
            legend.pager.hide();
            legend.display = false;
        } else {

            legend.group.show();
            legend.down.show();
            legend.up.show();
            legend.pager.show();
            legend.display = true;
        }
    });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3Bh7b/124/

Comment: Thanks, Working great, by the way, where can I found the details API you are using, like: legend.down.hide();
                        legend.up.hide();
                         legend.pager.hide();   , it is not documented on the Highcharts official site ?

Comment: You can use console.log(chart) then in your console (dev tools) you see all references. Second solution is source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide legend with pagination like this:

```
$('.highcharts-legend').hide();
```